# How can I add custom words to the suggested list in the text prediction feature in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, productivity, dictionary

I use the [text prediction feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2lhk.jpg) in Windows 10:

[image]

How can I add custom words to the suggested list?

Comment: You can view the user’s dictionary by navigating to Privacy -> Inking and clicking on the option to view the dictionary

Comment: @Ramhound thanks! Do you happen to know how to edit the list?  I couldn't see it on Privacy -> Inking: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqAXG.png

Comment: There is supposed to be a way to add and remove words, text based files are located in %AppData%\Microsoft\Spelling